# Python line.split to include a whitespace

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

If I have a string and want to return a word that includes a whitespace how would it be done?

For example, I have:

```
line = 'This is a group of words that include #this and @that but not ME ME'

response = [ word for word in line.split() if word.startswith("#") or  word.startswith('@')  or word.startswith('ME ')]

print response ['#this', '@that', 'ME']
```

So ME ME does not get printed because of the whitespace.

Thanks

Comment: What is your actual desired output?

Comment: How are the program supposed to know that ME ME is one word that contains a whitespace as opposed to two words? (How can a word even include a whitespace?)

Comment: ME ME is not a word but rather it's a prefix(ME) then space then the word(ME). I want the program to pick it all up. Apologies for not being clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just keep it simple:

```
line = 'This is a group of words that include #this and @that but not ME ME'

words = line.split()

result = []

pos = 0
try:
    while True:
        if words[pos].startswith(('#', '@')):
            result.append(words[pos])
            pos += 1
        elif words[pos] == 'ME':
            result.append('ME ' + words[pos + 1])
            pos += 2
        else:
            pos += 1
except IndexError:
    pass

print result
```

Think about speed only if it proves to be too slow in practice.

Answer (score 1):

From python Documentation:

> **string.split(s[, sep[, maxsplit]])**: Return a list of the words of the string s. If the optional second
>   argument sep is absent or None, the words are separated by arbitrary
>   strings of whitespace characters (space, tab, newline, return,
>   formfeed).

so your error is first on the call for split.

> > > > print line.split() 
> > > >         ['This', 'is', 'a', 'group', 'of', 'words', 'that', 'include', '#this', 'and', '@that', 'but', 'not', 'ME', 'ME']

I recommend to use [re](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) for splitting the string.  Use the **re.split(pattern, string, maxsplit=0, flags=0)**